# Can I read the same line from a text file multiple times with while loop?

Tags: vhdl

Edit: Okay I am able to re read the first line. Problem now is that it keeps repeat the first line only and doesn't move on to the next line. From all the loops I see, it suppose to look like it would work.

I am working on a program for simulation purposes which reads hex data byte by byte from a text file and outputs it in a 1 bit per clock cycle.

I would like to reuse the same line multiple times after reading it before moving on to another read line. For testing purposes of whether it could re read the same line I used

```
inline2 := new string'(inline.all);
```

and copied and paste the same code below and changing some of the read variables. Which worked I was able to read the same line twice, however I am planning to use a while loop to implement it for quite a number of readings and I have trouble doing so.
I was whether is it possible or did I make a mistake again.

Basically my goal is for text file first line containing `AA BB CC`, 2nd line containing `DD EE FF`.

Setting

```
signal Seqcount: integer = := 0
```

Using a (while Seqcount loop of <3) I would like the output to be

```
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
DD EE FF
DD EE FF
DD EE FF
```

I tried adding

```
While (Seqcount <3) loop 
inline := new string'(inline.all);
```

followed by my read codes. However, it only read the data once and stopped. Without looping again.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
LIBRARY STD;
USE STD.textio.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity readtext is
port (  
IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1: OUT    std_logic
);
end readtext;

ARCHITECTURE arch_name OF readtext IS


signal readdatainput : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal    linenumber : integer:=0; 
signal Bitreading : std_logic;
signal Bitcount : integer := 0;
signal SeqCount: integer := 1;

BEGIN


clock <= not (clock) after 0.5 ms;  

reading:
process
    file   infile    : text is in  "A.txt"; --A.txt contains AA 00 AA on the first line followed by BB 11 BB on next line. 
    variable inline    : line; --line number declaration
    variable inline2    : line; --line number declaration --test
    file file_RESULTS : text;
    variable inputdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    variable inputdata2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); --test

begin
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    while not endfile(infile) loop   
    readline(infile, inline);
    inline := new string'(inline.all); --I was hoping this refresh the inline
    while (SeqCount < 5) loop
inline := new string'(inline.all); --to copy line data to a new line
    while inline.all'length /= 0 loop
    hread (inline, inputdata);
    readdatainput <= inputdata;
    for i in inputdata'range loop
    Bitreading <= inputdata(i);
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= inputdata(i);
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    end loop;--end of byte
    inline := new string' (inline2.all);
    end loop;-- end of line
    SeqCount <= SeqCount+1; --this loops the program to read it a few more times. 
    end loop;   -- end of while loop condition go to next line.
Seqcount <= 1;
end loop;  -- end of file, it is suppose to repeat here
file_close(infile);  
end process reading;
 endoffile <='1';         --set signal to tell end of file read file is reached. 
END ARCHITECTURE arch_name;
```

It is able to read the first line of data and repeat for the number of times of loop however it doesnt go on to the next line.

Comment: There is no program nor operating system I know which allows you to read the same line again and again from a file. The nearest is to use the equivalent of e.g. `seek` in C.

Comment: Read the line once and then use it as many times as you need. You might need to capsule that functionality in a module or function.

Comment: inline2 will work as it is a copy of the original line. you can re-use it as many times as you want. Just remember to DEALLOCATE any line before you re-allocate it to prevent memory leaks. VHDL has no garbage collection.

Comment: As others have said, I think you have the right idea, it's just your code isn't working properly. Surely you want to (1) read a line from the file into `inline`; (2) copy `inline` to `inline2`; (3) read the information from `inline`; (4) copy `inline2` to `inline`; (5) repeat 3 and 4 as many times as you like.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor thanks I did not realised I could add another inline := new string'(inline2.all); statement to refresh it. I went to test it out and it is able to repeat my first line again. A problem now is it just repeats the first lines without moving on to the next line. Currently looking into it

Comment: 1. VHDL design, not program. 2. Processes suspend and resume in a wait statement. 3. No signal update occurs while any process has yet to resume and subsequently suspend. 4. There is no intervening wait statement following `Seqcount <= 1;` and susequent evaluation `(while (SeqCount < 5) loop`) for the next line. Possible solutions:  use a variable, use only the outer while loop, the rest for loop iteration schemes, or simply place `wait for 0 ms;` immediately after `Seqcount <= 1;`.

Comment: (And the answer to your yes/no question is yes.)